# Android WIFI disconnects

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I see the following log in the LogCat window; and during this time my WIFI disconnects!

```
05-11 09:17:39.559: V/WifiStateTracker(174): Changing supplicant state: COMPLETED ==> ASSOCIATED
05-11 09:17:39.559: I/WifiStateTracker(174): Ignore events that don't change the connectivity state, such as WPA rekeying operations.
05-11 09:17:39.589: V/WifiStateTracker(174): Changing supplicant state: COMPLETED ==> COMPLETED
05-11 09:17:39.589: V/WifiStateTracker(174): New network state is CONNECTED
05-11 09:17:39.599: D/NetworkStateTracker(174): setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=CONNECTED
05-11 09:17:39.609: E/NetUtils(174): need to remove the current default route before creating a new one
05-11 09:17:39.609: V/WifiStateTracker(174): Static IP configuration succeeded
05-11 09:17:39.609: D/NetworkStateTracker(174): setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=CONNECTED
```

I searched the net for Android WIFI states and found this:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html

Despite the fact that my WIFI sleep policy is "Never" I want to know why this happens?

Comment: how are you accessing the wifi connection ?? give that code

Comment: I'm not using any specific code that writteny by myself. I'm using a SIP client called Bria; it is not open source. But this error happens anyway is it not related I think to a specific software.

Comment: if u have enough time do this TEST .. (socket programing) send a hello string from your PC via wifi (wrt to your IP address and any port) and try to receive that string in your device and print it . (1) if that works fine your wifi PING is success (2) get a for loop at server(PC socket code) and sent 1000 integers with delay of 5seconds thisi if works **will establish that your long term connectivity is fine**

Comment: Thank you I will test it; but I want to know why this happens? For example if this is a bug or a natural thing.

Comment: i have very less experience with this topic . i am a student myself . my guess is bug maybe at the API you are using

Comment: sometimes the emulater needs some manual allowance like filesystem (not device the emulater at PC) so do ask your seniors or API vemdor if u need amy suchcconfiguration . **or try executing in a mobile device itself and add a toast for exception msg if any**